# How to detect taps on tableview row labels?

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I am building a iOS using Rubymotion.
In this app I got a Tableview with a lot of rows. Each row got three icons (labels) that I will be using for actions. How can I detect taps on these labels and act upon it? I also need to identify the row id for the parent row and exactly what type of label the user tapped since there are three on each row.

How can I do this?

Comment: I am not familiar with Rubymotion. But in native development for such task I use custom buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Use Button instead of labels. Add action methods to each button.